# How to create a user in azure ad using email address

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on creating a user in `azure ad`. For this, I am using [microsoft graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`. Below is the json post I am using:

```
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "displayName": "test",
    "mailNickname": "test",
    "userPrincipalName": "test@mytennantname.onmicrosoft.com",
    "passwordProfile" : {
      "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
      "password": "<password>"
     }
}
```

Using above data, I am able to create user in azure ad. User is also able to sign in using `test@mytennantname.onmicrosoft.com`. I wanted to know if is there any way I can save the external email id of the user for ex `test@gmail.com` in azure, so that he can use `test@gmail.com` to sign in. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domain, e.g. `gmail.com` is not in your tenant's verified domains, you cannot "create" the user.
You will need to use the B2B invitation features to invite the user.

That's this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

So you will need to make a POST to /invitations with a request body like:

```
{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "test@gmail.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.com"
}
```

Note these are the 2 mandatory properties, you can check what others are supported in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/invitation?view=graph-rest-1.0).
The redirect URI is where the user will be sent after they accept the invitation through the link they receive.
When you call this API, an email is sent to the user with a standard content.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this approach is that, it sends an invitation to user email address which I think we can turn it off. But the major problem is that it does not have an option setting the password. Is there any way I can mention the password as well in this json request. Thanks

Comment: No. That's up to the user, not you.